# Get Facebook Album Cover Photo URL with JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to stack so apologies in advance if I don't format this right.

I have a program which logs users into their Facebook account, I want to display their albums, so far I am just trying to get their Facebook album cover photo but I keep getting bad requests.

```
function getAlbumName(access_token, userID) {
  FB.api('/me/albums', { fields: 'id, name, cover_photo' }, function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    var ul = document.getElementById('albums');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      var
        album = response.data[i],
        li = document.createElement('li'),
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        img = document.createElement('img'),
        p = document.createElement('p');
        //a = document.createElement('a');

      img.src = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/" + album.id + "/"
      + album.cover_photo.id + "/picture?type=thumbnail&access_token=" + access_token;
      div.setAttribute('class', 'album.info');
      p.innerHTML = album.name;

      div.appendChild(img);
      div.appendChild(p);
      li.appendChild(div);
      ul.appendChild(li);
      //getAlbumPhotos();

      function getAlbumPhotos() {
        FB.api('me/' + album.id + '/photos', function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
          var parentli = document.getElementsByTagName(li);
          for (var j = 0; j < album.count; j++) {
            var
              photo = response.data[j],
              img = document.createElement('img').setAttribute("id", photo.id)
                .setAttribute('src', "http://graph.facebook.com/" + album.id + "/" + photo.id);

            childul = document.createElement('ul');

            li.appendChild(img);
            childul.appendChild(li);
            parentli.appendChild(childul);
          }
        })
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Currently with this code I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
GET http://graph.facebook.com/[user-id]/[album-id]/[cover-photo-id]/picture?type=thumbnail&access_token=[access-token] 400 (Bad Request)
```

Let me know if there is something I forgot to add to help out, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good format, don't worry :)

`album` is actually undefined because you don't pass it in parameter of your function. So it is not in the `getAlbumPhotos`' scope.

Just replace the declaration of `getAlbumPhotos` by

```
function getAlbumPhotos(album){
```

and uncomment your line which is calling this function and add `album` in parameter.

```
getAlbumPhotos(album);
```

Tip :

You can put the function `getAlbumPhotos` outside the for loop.